# Please display additional user information on the Android app user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, android-app

When I'm viewing a user profile, it's more often than not to gauge this user within the community. How long they have been a member, how active they have been, when was their last activity and of course, what content are they contributing. This is accentuated when the user in question is a relatively new user. I would want to know this in order to make my response or comment more informative and to not be too harsh on inexperienced users.

One good measure I use to identify a new user is their join date. I would like to request that the "member for" field be added to the profile page for users on the mobile application just as it is when viewing the desktop version.

The "last seen" field would also be useful. It's useful to me on the desktop version to know more or less when/if to expect a response from a user after leaving them a comment/answer. It would useful on the mobile version for the same reasons.

---

I just realized that this information **is** available on the mobile version of the webiste. If it was decided that this information is important enough to also appear on the mobile web version, why not include it on the native mobile applications?

Comment: Hmmm... now that the iphone app is in alpha... Perhaps it's time to create a more generic mobile-app tag...

Comment: On the contrary, [tag:mobile-app] is ambiguous. Since the two apps are developed independently, bugs and feature requests need to be handled independently.

Comment: Thanks for the update @ArieLitovsky! Would it be correct to assume that if it is decided to go ahead with this feature; it would be also added to the android version?

Comment: @Lix not immediately, we don't try to keep perfect feature parity, though I'm sure we can squeeze it in the future

Comment: This info is already available in the iOS version of the app. I'm removing iOS from the tags.