# Accessing site-specific profile pages from app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I have the impression I cannot access my site-specific profile pages from the android app. I mean, if I use the option bar, I certainly do not get access to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/135592/mickg), but only to a subset of its contents in the form below:

[image]

Is this a bug? Or is there a reason for this? And if so, which is it? Or maybe I'm missing a way to do this... if so, how can I?

**Update**

Taking comments into account, this is by design and no bug, no way to get "the full details". So I will retag this to [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and specify I'd like access to:

- The full list of Qs and As;
- The list of badges.

Can has?

Comment: This is by design, and there is already a feature request asking to get the full details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213907/please-display-additional-user-information-on-the-mobile-app-user-profile

Comment: @ShadowWizard the linked question does not really ask for "the full details", but just the "last seen" and "join date" fields. I am asking because I often find my own Qs/As from that page, and as of now I only have a very partial list, and combining that with [the banner for reading a post in the app gone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267343/possible-bugs-in-mobile-site) I end up having to either read/edit/whatnot the posts from the site or to share them on Facebook and then open them in the app. PS the link just before was found precisely from the profile page, from the mac.

Comment: Also, I cannot know what badges I have.

Comment: True, hence not dupe. You can change this question to feature request asking to add the details you want, instead of just asking if they are available (they are not) or reporting it as a bug (which it is not)

Comment: @ShadowWizard done.